# I can't see the continue button

Tags: javascript, html, macos, visual-studio, text-based

I am a beginner programmer working on a text based game in Visual Studio and the continue button doesn't show up on the webpage. Is there something I missed?

```
            <p></p>
            <fieldset></fieldset>
            <button id="resetButton" class="reset">Restart</button>
            <a id="continueButton" class="continue" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script> src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on what I see here, there's no text in your anchor, so it wouldn't show up

Comment: You should put some text inside the a tag ex: `<a>Continue</a>`. Btw, your script is wrong, should be like this `<script src="js.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your continueButton element is using the `<a>` tag with nothing in it, so there is nothing to display. Add something inside your `<a>` tag or change it to a `<button>` like the resetButton element.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="resetButton" class="reset">Restart</button>
        <a id="continueButton" class="continue" href="javascript:void(0);">Continue</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any text in the *a* tag.

`<a id="continueButton" class="continue" href="javascript:void(0);">PUT YOUR TEXT HERE</a>`

Comment: You should put this in a snippet like the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this issue is using developer tools on browsers (Personally, I like Firefox). As you can see from the image, there is something on the right called the box model for the `a` tag that's been selected.

[image: Without text in between a tags]

The height of the `a` tag is `16` whereas the width is `0`. This makes sense as to what you're seeing on the browser. You have a box that is `0x16` (under box model).

Now if I add some text in between the `a` tags (added the text `AAA`) you can see that the box is now `34.65x16`.

[image: With text in between a tags]

Some resources to learn about the box model :

https://web.dev/learn/css/box-model/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model